# Does vitamio support encrypted HLS streaming

Tags: android, encryption, http-live-streaming, vitamio

I can play the `.m3u8` with the native `MediaPlayer` in android. But, I don't want to be rejected by Gingerbread users. I find a player named `Vitamio` said to be a wonderful player that can play HLS streaming on 2.x. However, when I import it into my project, the app is not responding, leaving me the log saying `avformat_open_input: I/O error -5`. The `.m3u8` is encrypted, and can be played with the native `MediaPlayer` in android on my MOTOROLA XT875.

I searched for the error info, and find this[Errors videos not played -- Vitamio](http://www.vitamio.org/en/docs/FAQ/2013/0509/14.html).

So, does vitamio really support the encrypted HLS streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank U Palejandro! However, according to [Vitamio Docs](http://www.vitamio.org/en/docs/news/2013/1231/23.html), the latest SDK v4.2 supports the encrypted HLS. `Support AES-128 encrypt for HTTP Live Streaming.` So, the answer is yes.

Maybe, the problem has something to do with the different SDK version or other issue. I fixed this problem by just testing it on another cell phone...

Comment: @RohitSuthar Apple is the leader of HLS. So, you can find all the HLS docs [HLS Overview - Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply but i need for android, so tell me how can i do `AES-128 encrypt for HTTP Live Streaming for ANDROID`??

Comment: @RohitSutharMumbai Sorry but I did not encrypt the media file on android, it was done using OS X.

Comment: ok fine, now tell me how to play `AES-128 encrypt HTTP Live Streaming on ANDROID`? Do you have any idea?

Comment: If you have the encrypted HLS media file or url, just use the vitamio player, set the .m3u8 file as the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Vitamio's website: [Vitamio feautes not support](http://www.vitamio.org/en/docs/FAQ/2013/0509/11.html) says:

> Doesn't support encrypted videos (such as DRM), embeded m3u8 (if in m3u8 including video links cann't be played, then vitamio will stop playing video, not skip).

so, the answer to your question is unfortunately no.
If you want to play encrypted HLS in android devices, you can create something like local server in your phone, which will download and decrypt encrypted .ts files and then create your own m3u8 playlist for mediaplayer

Comment: Thank U Palejandro! However, according to [Vitamio Docs](http://www.vitamio.org/en/docs/news/2013/1231/23.html), the latest SDK v4.2 supports the encrypted HLS. `Support AES-128 encrypt for HTTP Live Streaming.` So, the answer seems to be yes. But We cant afford the player and removed it from our app. What a pity!

Comment: I read that too, but I didnt try it yet, so I cant tell, if it works or not. What do you mean, you can afford the player ? and can you tell me, how your system should work, maybe we can figure it out together..

Comment: I did try the SDK, and it works. I mean we cant afford the price. As shown [Authorize](http://www.vitamio.org/en/License/), we must pay to use the SDK in our app.